# ER_NO_DB_ERROR: No database though database is present

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-mysql

I am learning to create application using node js , I am connecting node js to mysql, the connection is successful , but after that when I am giving "select" command from node file it's throwing "ER_NO_DB_ERROR: No database selected" this error.
Below are my files :

config.js

```
module.export ={
server : "localhost/phpmyadmin/",
port : "3306",
database : "newdb",
username : "root",
password : ""
}
```

connection.js

```
var dbConfig = require("./config")
var sqlInst = require("mysql")
 var con = {};
module.exports.createCon = function(callback){

 con = sqlInst.createConnection(dbConfig);

con.connect(function(err){

    if(err)        
    {
        console.error(err);  
       // callback(err);
    }
    else{      
        console.log("connected");
    }

})

module.exports.instSql = function(callback){
    let sql = "SELECT * FROM `producdesc`";
    con.query(sql,(err,result)=>{
    if(err){
      console.log(err);
      res = err;
    }
    else {
        res = result;
    }

    });
  //  return res;
}

}
```

server.js file:

```
const exp = require("express");
var connect = require("./connection")
const app = exp();

app.listen('3000',()=>{
console.log('server strated at port 3000');
})

app.get('/connect',(req,res)=>{
console.log("hello");
connect.createCon();
res.send("connected to database");
})

app.get('/show',(req,res)=>{
let prodRes ;
console.log("in show");
prodRes=connect.instSql();
   res.send(prodRes);
  })
```

The error comes only when I try to "http://localhost:3000/show" , the database and the table are present in the database.

Could someone please let me know the issue

Comment: does your `newdb` exist?

Comment: Yes the newdb exits

Comment: what about `producdesc` table inside `newdb`?)

Comment: I had already mentioned in the question everything is present

Comment: Are you sure your db host in running on `localhost/phpmyadmin/`?
I would say not ... phpmyadmin is MySQL client not server.

Comment: I agree with @froston. If you are using default settings for the db, then it is probably running on `localhost:3306`.

Answer (score 0):

In node `mysql`, the properties are called `host` and `user`, not `server` and `username`. https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#connection-options

So, change your config to:

```js
module.export = {
  host: 'localhost/phpmyadmin/', // This was changed
  port: 3306,
  database: 'newdb',
  user: 'root', // This was changed
  password: ''
};
```